# Grep first string matching regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to get the first string that matches my regular expression. 
For example I have the String

> RCPT from unknown[211.147.3.74]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [211.147.3.74];

and my script looks like this:

```
IP=`echo $LINE | grep -E -o --max-count=1 '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'`

echo $IP
```

As result I get

> 211.147.3.74 211.147.3.74

But I would like to get the IP only once. I tried 'grep --max-count=1' but there are still two ip's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LINE='RCPT from unknown[211.147.3.74]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [211.147.3.74];'
ipn='(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
IP=`echo $LINE | grep -E -o "$ipn\.$ipn\.$ipn\.$ipn" | head -1`
echo "$IP"
```

or [from here](https://superuser.com/questions/202818/match-ip-address)

```
echo "$LINE"  | perl -MRegexp::Common=net -ne '/($RE{net}{IPv4})/ and print "$1\n"'
```